# ORACLE: How to call a Stored procedure with BOTH in and out parameters

Tags: oracle, delphi

I have a StoredProcedure in Oracle with a In Parameter and a our paramterer (a cursor)

The procedure is defined as following:

```
PROCEDURE GetAccessObjects2(ALotteryID IN VARCHAR2, AAccessObjects OUT CURSOR_TYPE) AS
BEGIN
  OPEN AAccessObjects FOR
    SELECT  AccessObjectID, AccessObjectName
    FROM    AccessObjects;
END;
```

Then I try to call it from Delphi:

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ADOStoredProc1 do
  begin
    Connection := ADOConnection1;
    CursorType := ctOpenForwardOnly;
    MaxRecords := 5000;
    ProcedureName := 'DDK.GetAccessObjects2';
    with Parameters.AddParameter do
    begin
      Name := 'ALotteryID';
      DataType := ftString;
      Value := 'TEST';
    end;
  end;

  ADOStoredProc1.Open;
end;
```

But then I got an exception :

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'GETACCESSOBJECTS2' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

PS: `ADOConnection1` is a valid connection to the database.

According to [this web page](http://support.embarcadero.com/jp/article/36155) it isn't  necessary to define a parameter for the cursor (AAccessObjects) but oracle thinks otherwise.

So in short how do I call my SP from Delphi with ADO

**UPDATE**

I've tried to provide the curser ad a parameter:

```
  with ADOStoredProc1 do
  begin
    Connection := ADOConnection1;
    CursorType := ctOpenForwardOnly;
    MaxRecords := 5000;
    ProcedureName := 'DDK.GetAccessObjects2';
    Parameters.CreateParameter('ALotteryID', ftString, pdInput, 255, 'TEST');
    Parameters.CreateParameter('AAccessObjects', ftCursor, pdOutput, 0, null);
  end;

  ADOStoredProc1.Open;
```

But then I get an Exception inside ADO:

> Parameter object is improperly defined

Comment: Have you tried to call `ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.Refresh` after setting the `ProcedureName`, and then set the `ALotteryID` parameter value directly (without the `AddParameter`). The `.Refresh` should return  the parameters ready to use from the server.

Comment: No. I'll try that later on.

Comment: Where is ***AccessObjectName*** defined?

Comment: That's a field in a table in the database

Comment: I guess you mean field, but fair enough. What is the definition of CURSOR_TYPE? Is it defined somewhere as REF CURSOR, perhaps?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot to include the definition for that

Comment: @kobik made no diffrence

Comment: The one difference that I can see between your code and that in link is that there the cursor is provided as an in out parameter. For sanity's sake it might be worth trying that.

Comment: One thing to consider is that cursors may be server side or client side. If the parameter is out, that implies a server side cursor, but maybe ADO expects a client side cursor. I don't know that for a fact - it is just a thought. If that is the case the cursor parameter need to be in out, I think.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
ParamType := ptOutput
```

Not sure what the datatype will be for a CURSOR_TYPE in Oracle.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about the CURSOR_TYPE in Oracle. But I do know that there is a ptOutput Paramter type. I have used it with other databases.

Comment: What I suspect you are suggesting is to pass the cursor as a parameter, but the link in the OP indicates that this is wrong.

Comment: @Dsm If I do that I get an exception inside the ADO driver : "Parameter object is improperly defined"

Comment: I belive the solution will be switching to ODAC